# Android - Login and share with Google Plus

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, share

I want my app to login and share with Google PLus. I tried sample app "Plus" ,but my app requires login page in Popup ..Like in social auth..

Comment: What's the question? - provide some code

Comment: Please post your question, not statement. How we can help you?